# How to gzip Certain Extension in All-Directories?

Tags: linux, unix, gzip

I have been trying to gzip .BRIK files on my iMac. However, the files with this extension are scattered everywhere and they are multi-level deep. What I have been doing is going folder by folder and use this

```
gzip *BRIK
```

However, it is tedious and will take a long time to do one folder at a time. I also tried

```
gzip -r *BRIK
```

or

```
gzip -r *BRIK ./
```

They did not work. Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm not sure it would work well on iOS, but I'd use `find "$root_dir" -name '*BRIK' -exec gzip {} +`

Answer (score 1):

The tool you're looking for is `find` to discover the files and `xargs` to call `gzip` with their names.

```
find . -name '*.BRIK' -print0 | xargs -0 gzip
```

The use of `-print0` and `-0` here allows this to work smoothly with directories and files with spaces in their names.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to `find`, recursive globbing in zsh is super handy and easy to use. In your case in zsh you can simply:

```
gzip **/*.BRIK
```

(Since Catalina, zsh has been the default shell in macOS.)

Comment: Also works in bash 4+ with the globstar option : https://ideone.com/24r4md

Comment: I think https://stackoverflow.com/a/68577549/6607497 is preferable, especially when there are many files and/or deep hierarchies.